# view to take all remaining space storyboard

Tags: iphone, xcode, storyboard

how we can design UI with storyboard to make a view take all remaining space.

Design Requirements:
I have a View that has two Label (Data and New) and I want new to be displayed at bottom and then take the data to take all remain space inside view.

I ended up designing storyboard like this which works fine but have questions/doubts

1. attached screenshot, vertical specing constrain defined as 10px space between both labels but why UI preview shows +55.6?
2. is three better way to desing same UI?

[image: created storyboard]

Comment: This "+55.7" is yellow, which means that it's not the real value, but the current "W.I.P." one. Try the "Update Frames" button in the bottom right corner of the Storyboard editor—it should update your Storyboard to display its actual layout, all yellow markers should disappear.

Comment: @lazarevzubov Thanks that helps, but in my opinion, it feels like the storyboard UI design is unnecessarily complex, for example, I want this yellow view to expand and collapse based on content within the data-view but I have to provide a fixed height first to complete the horizontal and vertical design (otherwise storyboard Xcode was complaining about missing constraints) and then delete that in order to have dynamic height.

Comment: Your autolayout settings seems correct, the issue is that you are doing it inside a `UITableviewCell`. In order to make the cell have the same height as the `TableView`, you have to set the size of the cell in code

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I want the height to be dynamic and I don't want to set height through code. through storyboard constraints, I am able to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... and then take the `Data` to take all remaining space

This means `Data` label should have a lower `vertical` `content hugging priority` than the `New` label.

> why UI preview shows +55.6?

Because it is designed for prototyping it is telling that what you are seeing in the preview has exactly `+55.6` with what you are going to see at runtime.

<sub>⚠️ Note that it's about the spacing, not the height. On **dynamic cells** settings, the `rowHeight` set on the `UITableView` always overrides the individual cells' rowHeight.</sub>

> is three better way to design the same UI?

There is no such a thing as **better**. You should pick what it most suits you and your team. For example:

- You can use `StackView` to reduce the constraints, but it may have less dynamicity than autolayout.
- You can use `Xib` files to enhance reusability, but they may be a bit old-style and also make your project file bigger
- You can use code to reduce Git conflicts, but you may lose the drag-and-drop feature
- etc.

Each method comes with its cons and pros.

<sub>In **MY opinion** (which is not the best), go with the `StackView` when your layout is `vertical` or `horizontal`. This way you also prepare for SwiftUI regular layout mechanism.</sub>